# In Angular, how do I manipulate what shows in the option tag based on a previous selection?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm struggling to find a second solution to how I have this implemented. First I will show you how it's implemented then explain how it needs to be changed.

html:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <h4>Session: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01"
            (change)="sessionDataChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="sessionReportFilter.sessionName">
      <option value="null">Select session...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let session of sessionData; index as i;"
              [value]="i">
        {{session.sessionName}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <h4>Report Date: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01"[(ngModel)]="sessionReportFilter.fileName">
      <option value="">Select report date...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let report of reports"
              [value]="report">
        {{report}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) ="orderExceptionReportData()">Retrieve</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class OrderExceptionReportComponent implements OnInit {

  public sessionData: ExceptionReportSessionData[] = [];
  public sessionReportData: ExceptionReportData;
  public sessionReportFilter: ExceptionReportFilter = {
    sessionName: "Washington",
    fileName: "EXCEPTION20130211060056882.csv"
  }
  reports = [];
  cols = [
    { header: 'ItemId' },
    { header: 'AltItemId' },
    { header: 'GenName' },
    { header: 'StationName' },
    { header: 'HospitalCode' },
    { header: 'Facility' },
    { header: 'Reason' }
  ];

  constructor(private orderExceptionReportService: OrderExceptionReportService) {  
  }

  public async getExceptionReportSessionData(): Promise<void> {
    return this.orderExceptionReportService.GetExceptionReportSessionData()
      .then(
        data => {
          this.sessionData = data;
        });   
  }

  public async orderExceptionReportData(): Promise<void> {
    return this.orderExceptionReportService.OrderExceptionReport(this.sessionReportFilter)
      .then(
        data => {
          this.sessionReportData = data;
          console.log(this.sessionReportData)
        });
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getExceptionReportSessionData();

  }

  sessionDataChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value; 

    if (isNaN(Number(value))) {
      this.reports = [];
    } else {
      this.reports = this.sessionData[Number(value)].reportFiles;
    }
    console.log(this.reports);
  }

}
```

Right now as you can see in my first drop down the `[value]` is set to i and that's so the function I have called on `(change)` can get the correct data show in the second drop down. Well I need `[value]` to be set to session.sessionName because I am using two way databinding so that when the user clicks the retrieve button the correct data is being sent to the function. How can I change the implementation so that based on which `Session` the user selects in the drop downs only the `ReportDates` associated with the `Session` are correct so that I can use two way data binding to make the function call on the button `Retrieve`?

Comment: please find my answer below.

Comment: @AakashGarg updated the question

Comment: can you share result of   this.sessionData ? (pic of console log will be great)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to update the `sessionData` of the report select when `change` event occurs on session select. You have several way of doing this I will propose you a simple one,

*component.ts*

```
sessions: ExceptionReportSessionData[] = []; // the list obtained from service
reports: string[] = []; // the reports list

sessionChange(evt) {
    const value = evt.target.value;
    console.log(`session index: ${value}`);
    if (isNaN(Number(value))) {
        this.reports = [];
    } else {
        this.reports = this.sessions[Number(value)].ReportFiles;
    }
    console.log(`reports: ${this.reports}`);
}
```

*component.html*

```html
<div class="input-group">
    <h4>Session: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm"
    (change)="sessionChange($event.target.value)">
        <option value="null">Select session...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let session of sessions; index as i;"
        value="{{i}}">{{session.SessionName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <h4>Report Date: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm">
        <option value="null">Select report date...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let report of reports"
        value="report">{{report}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Pretty straight forward implementation of the above idea. Like I mention there are several ways to do this.

[Working Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wim5gw)

Comment: All I am getting is an empty array in my second selection box.

Comment: Sorry, I wrongly bind to `selectionChange` event of the wrong select. We want to listen changes on the session select, and on change call the handler function `sessionChange`. Now check if the function it is been call when you make selections on the session select.

Comment: still getting any empty array. I've updated my question with your implementation. Can you see if maybe I've made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: The part of the selects looks fine .. It looks kind of weird the way you are handling the service response .. is the session select actually getting data? .. I think you do not need the `async` and there is also no need to return a value in `getExceptionReportSessionData` function .. When the value of `sessionData` change the template will be updated, that means the options will be loaded

Comment: There's a couple reason's I'm using async but that's another discussion. I updated my question again with how my service response is really implemented, that other way I was just testing something. Yes I am getting real data back because my first select box fills with the correct data from my database

Comment: OK, log the value that is receiving the handler function `sessionDataChange` and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215378/discussion-between-jaden-adams-and-cabesuon).

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to :-

```
<div class="input-group">
    <h4>Session: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01"
            (change)="sessionDataChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="sessionReportFilter.sessionName">
      <option value="null">Select session...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let session of sessionData; index as i;"
              [value]="session.sessionName">
        {{session.sessionName}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <h4>Report Date: </h4>
    <select class="custom-select form-control-sm" id="inputGroupSelect01"[(ngModel)]="sessionReportFilter.fileName">
      <option value="">Select report date...</option>
      <option *ngFor="let report of reports"
              [value]="report">
        {{report}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) ="orderExceptionReportData()">Retrieve</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change your typescript method to :-

```
sessionDataChange(evt) {
    const sessionName= evt.target.value; 

    if (!sessionName || sessionName.length === 0) {
      this.reports = [];
    } else {
      this.reports = this.sessionData.find((session) => session.sessionName === sessionName).reportFiles;
    }
    console.log(this.reports);
  }
```

Comment: @JadenAdams did you try the solution i provided?

Comment: Yes and no luck